# PayPal post transaction data not being passed

Tags: php, html, paypal

Ok, I am at a loss.  I am sure there is something really obvious that I am missing, but in testing my transaction in the sandbox, I am not re-directing automatically back to my website, and I am not seeing any data... POST, GET or otherwise.  Here is my PayPal form:  I have tried Auto Return without PDT, Auto Return with PDT, neither Auto Return or PDT... running out of ideas.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="MichaelsWeddingPhoto@comcast.net" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="shipping2_1" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Comments" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.masphotopdx.com/process.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.masphotopdx.com/mas_cart.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.masphotopdx.com/" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="MRS9734" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="MRS9734_unsigned_7Hx11W_Glossy_Paper_$55" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="55" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="MRS1411-13" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="MRS1411-13_unsigned_7Hx11W_Glossy_Paper_$55" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="55" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Larry" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Smith" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="1421 Pink Park Place" />
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Los Angeles" />
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="WA" />
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="99802" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="PinkLarry@LAX.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value="555" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="121" />
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value="2121" />
<table>
<tr><td><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDT you need to enable it and Auto-Return in your PayPal account profile.  For POST you need rm=2.

All of that said, PDT is only recommended for displaying details on the return page.  You don't want to be updating your database or doing anything that you need to make sure happens with every order on the return page.  This is because even with Auto-Return enabled the user could still close their browser prior to the return happening.

Instead, use IPN, which will be triggered regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site or not.

Comment: Yes, I can see that I would not want to do anything mission critical on the return side.  I was just hoping to get a confirmation to display and maybe do a few quick checks on data if the customer made it back.  IPN seems pretty complicated for me (small business).  I will try rm=2 tomorrow, but I am not even getting tx_id bounced back on the auto-return... which in the sandbox doesn't appear to happen.  Very frustrating.

Comment: I tried rm=2 in the sandbox (I refined the action and method as Machavity suggested... now I get a response from sandbox with method post, that's good), activated Auto Return and PDT in my preferences.  Now I get a bunch of post data returned to me.  This is good.  I am still not actually auto returning however... in the sandbox, user has to deliberately click return to my website on completion... I thought this would be automatic upon transaction completion?

Comment: I think I know what is going on, but no idea what to do about it.  With rm=2, the sandbox returns a ton of information, but no PDT and no Auto Return.  Nada.  Zip.  I vastly simplified my button code and same result.  It behaves as if PDT and Auto Return are both turned off.  Then it hits me... just because my parent account has PDT and AR turned on doesn't mean that the sandbox account does... and there is where I stop.  No idea how to set up these to be active within the sandbox.  Kind of limits the usefulness of the sandbox, no?

Comment: Well, yeah, you're right.  Your "parent", or live PayPal account has nothing to do with your sandbox account.  You need to log in to your sandbox account and change it in that profile the same way you do with your live account, or whatever you're considering your parent account.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form tag should be

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

Next, make sure your business Sandbox has a PDT url specified.
Third, have you tried IPN it see if you get a response that way?

Comment: I did try the sandbox using "post" and immediately got stopped with the message that post was not supported.  I thought that was interesting.  Is there a different sandbox for use with PDT?!?!

Comment: You know, IPN is essentially the same thing as PDT except that it happens in a separate script from the checkout flow.  You have an IPN listener that receives the POST data, verifies it with PayPal, etc. just like PDT does.  I'd really recommend you just use IPN, but you shouldn't be having any issues with PDT in the sandbox.  I know I've used it plenty in the past.